# How to add TinyMCE to Comfortable Mexican Sofa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, tinymce, tinymce-4, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I'm evaluating the Rails 4 based CMS Comfortable Mexican Sofa. There is a Wiki entry on how to configure it to use TinyMCE here: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Replacing-default-wysiwyg-editor-with-tinymce

However it doesn't work for me. Any ideas? Or ways to configure another free WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"?  Please, post some logs or what you have tried.

Comment: Simply that when I open the admin pages, the text fields are not WYSIWYG, but rather plain text fields.

Comment: If you getting default wysiwyg that means you did something wrong. If you don't get wysiwyg at all that means that your field is plain text. Make sure it's defined as {{ cms:page:content:rich_text }}. Also note that in master, and in next patch selector will change to `textarea[data-cms-rich-text]`.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.12.0 TinyMCE is the standard editor, so you should be good.

Comment: I think this answer is confusing at best. Instead of solving the person's issue with the empty wiki entry, it gives him false hopes about the fact that he can succeed, when in reality, he really just needed your help.